# SQL Self Join with MAX and Group By

Tags: sql, self-join

I have the below table data

```
ID      Amt EOP LID
==================================
1   10  3/31/2014   11

2   10  3/31/2014   12

3   5   3/31/2014   13

4   15  2/28/2014   11

5   10  2/28/2014   12

6   15  2/28/2014   13

7   5   1/31/2014   11

8   15  4/30/2014   12

9   10  4/30/2014   13

10  5   5/31/2014   11

11  20  5/31/2014   12

12  25  5/31/2014   13
```

I need to write a query which when specified  EOP = 5/31/2014 would return the Sum(Amt) group by LID
and it would then compare it with the Sum(Amt) for the previous month i.e EOP=4/30/2014 group by LID and return only those LID where the values are diffrent.

Comment: in your requirement about the query. can you explain the last part.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the trick (SQL Server syntax):
The requirement is a bit unclear to me...

```
Select a.LID, a.currentmonth, b.lastmonth
from
    (select Sum(amt) as currentmonth, LID
     from MyTable
     where EOP = '2014-05-31'
     Group By LID ) a
left outer join 
    (select Sum(amt) as lastmonth, LID
     from MyTable
     where EOP = dateadd(month, -1, '2014-05-31')
     Group By LID) b on a.LID = b.LID
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09632/7